# Java scanner.nextInt throws NoSuchElement second time around

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

So I have a loop that runs which takes input from the user via a scanner and System.in. The scanner is just called s. I use s.nextInt to get an int for my switch, where I have a lot of cases, so the user has some choices. Now in one of those cases, I use another scanner, and when I close it and the function terminates (which takes me back to my while loop) I want to take a new int from the user, to choose the next thing they want to do. This time around it throws an NoSuchElementException. I used the "I'm before" and "I'm after" and the userrequest = s.nextInt is where I get the error. Any ideas? My function is way too long to post, but it doesn't really do anything that should interfere, except open a new scanner, but I have other functions which does that, but doesn't break it.

```
        while (on) {
            System.out.println("What may I do for you today? ");
            System.out.println("I'm before");
            int userrequest = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println("I'm after");
            switch (userrequest) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("");........
```

EDIT: Okay, I edited out some non important stuff from the function. This is the function it runs, before returning to my while loop:

```
 public static void buysystem(Connection con, Scanner sysbuy) {
        System.out.println("What system do you want to buy?");
        String sysreq = sysbuy.next().toUpperCase();

        try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String query = "SQL";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            rs.next();
            String nome = rs.getString("noob");
            int price = rs.getInt("cpuprice") + rs.getInt("ramprice") + rs.getInt("mainboardprice") + rs.getInt("casesprice") + rs.getInt("gfxprice");
            System.out.println("How many systems do you want to buy?");
            int sysamount = sysbuy.nextInt(); 
            //NEED TO MAKE CHECK AMOUNT FUNCTION
            int realprice;
            if (sysamount>10){
                realprice = (price*130/100)-((price*130/100*120/100)-(price*130/100));
                System.out.println("You want to buy " + sysamount + " of the system: " + sysreq + " for the price of " + realprice + "?");
                System.out.println("Yes/No?");
                String yesno = sysbuy.next();
                if (yesno.toUpperCase().equals("YES")){
                    System.out.println("You just bought " + sysamount + " of the system " + sysreq + " for the price of " + realprice);
                    //UPDATE DB
                }
            }
            else{
                realprice = (price*130/100)-((price*130/100*(sysamount*2+100-2)/100)-(price*130/100));
                System.out.println("You want to buy " + sysamount + " of the system: " + sysreq + " for the price of " + realprice + "?");
                System.out.println("Yes/No?");
                String yesno = sysbuy.next();
                if (yesno.toUpperCase().equals("YES")){
                    System.out.println("You just bought " + sysamount + " of the system " + sysreq + " for the price of " + realprice);
                    //UPDATE DB
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Print me");
    }
```

I get this error now:

```
You just bought 1 of the system SERVER1 for the price of 7540
Print me
What may I do for you today?
I'm before
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at DBtest.requestHandler(DBtest.java:43)
        at DBtest.main(DBtest.java:24)
```

Comment: `int userrequest = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());`.

Comment: But isn't that the same? EDIT: Just tried it, still get the error.

Comment: @Tiny , Why will `Scanner#nextInt()` will not work ?

Comment: @StupidQuestions , What is the Input you are passing to `nextInt() method` ?

Comment: @NeerajJain I do Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: @StupidQuestions , nextInt() will ask you for Input an Integer you are not entering it !!!

Comment: @NeerajJain No I'm not entering it because it throws an error immediatly

Comment: @StupidQuestions can you please paste your entire output window, including your input. Although my answer below answered your initial question as to why you were receiving the NoSuchElement exception it is better practice to ask a new question then transforming this question since users searching later will be confused.

Comment: Do not pass `Connection` and `Scanner` as method parameters. Use instead `Scanner` in your client program (the `main()` method) and pass just the value that you receive from `Scanner`. You are nowhere closing `Connection`, `Statement` (or `PreparedStatement`) and `ResultSet`. They should always be used in a shortest possible scope which is usually the method which they are being used in. They are otherwise likely to cause a probable memory leak at a certain time. All of those exceptions are also supposed to be caught by a client program. Other methods are supposed to (re)throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create multiple Scanners, instead use one scanner and use it inside your function or pass it to it if it is out of scope.

You created multiple Scanners, which you should not do, but also closed the second scanner. When you closed that scanner you closed the input stream which both scanners are using (the System's inputstream). This is what caused your crash.

Comment: He is creating only one `Scanner  Object`, and probably that too outside the `While loop`

Comment: He has the `s` Scanner instance along with the `sysbuy`. Not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Now I use only 1 scanner but I get a NumberFormatException: For Input String "". So I somehow put "" in System.in? How is that possible?

Comment: @StupidQuestions , then problem is that you are actually not passing anything to this method and just `clicking enter` !!!

Comment: @NeerajJain I press enter to submit my 'Yes', but that's it. I don't press enter afterwards

Comment: @chrissukhram , i was talking for the 1st code snippet , and for the 2nd code snippet I think he is only creating `1 instance` !!

Comment: @Neeraj Jain, but they are both in the same program using System.in, this will cause issues, especially when returning to use the original one when his while loop repeats.

Comment: @chrissukhram I will edit OP to include error message